# Cannot boot or shut down on Fedora 25 with last kernels is it a nouveau issue

Tags: fedora, boot, shutdown, nouveau

I own a Dell XPS 9650 that has a GTX 1050 graphic cards.
I run Fedora 25 and the last 2 kernels are just unusable...

1. 4.10.12-200.fc25.x86_64 -> I cannot boot (loading stops after the luks password)
2. 4.10.13-200.fc25.x86_64 -> I cannot shut down, and I get a nouveau failed to create channel 22 error

Is there any trick to deal with those issues ?

Comment: How can you have shutdown issues if the machine doesn't boot?  That's a bit unclear.

Comment: @JuliePelletier the first kernel does not boot, the second kernel does not shut down... Hope that's clearer

Comment: Did you try anything to fix either case like adding `nouveau.modeset=0` to the kernel parameters?

Comment: I just searched for your problem and 90% of the people get similar problems to yours on 4.10 with any driver they try to install unless they disable ACPI.  Perhaps it would be a good time to consider complaining to NVidia about their lack of support for other operating systems.  That is the reason behind all those problems.  Open source developers are forced to guess on how the card operates because NVidia doesn't share any information with the public.

Comment: I am actually thinking about installing nvidia drivers and forgeting about nouveau forever...

Comment: Nouveau does not currently have support for the 10xx series of Nvidia cards. Best stick with the Nvidia proprietary drivers until nouveau catches up.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled nouveau and installed nvidia drivers, following [this tutorial](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/#screenshots) 
Problem solved

Comment: Good for you...  Hopefully it remains stable for at least a few months.